# Enable voltage doesn't change on LTC2950 pushbutton on/off chip

Tags: power-supply, pcb, circuit-design, integrated-circuit

I'm troubleshooting a problem with an [LTC2950](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/295012fd.pdf) chip, specifically this version from [Digikey](https://www.digikey.ca/en/products/detail/analog-devices-inc/LTC2950CDDB-1-TRMPBF/1232647). The LTC's enable pin is connected to the enable pins on an[LMR15430](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lmr51430.pdf) regulator configured to provide a 5V output, and an [OKR-T/3-W12-C](https://www.murata.com/products/productdata/8807038550046/okr-t3-w12.pdf). The LTC chip is meant to assert the enable pin high or low whenever the PB pin is pulled low by a momentary pushbutton. Right now the design is considering either an [ITS13FR2ST](https://www.ckswitches.com/media/1894/its.pdf) or an [TL6215RF200RDT](https://mm.digikey.com/Volume0/opasdata/d220001/medias/docus/2119/TL6215_Series.pdf).

The problem I'm running into is that as soon as 12V is applied to the circuit, the EN pin goes to 1.495V, enabling the regulators and it doesn't change no matter how often or long the button is pushed.

-Update: The chip was reflowed and now the enable pin is being held low constantly. However, Hearth pointed out that the chip is open drain and that if the regulators lake an internal pull-up, I'm hooped. Also, the reflow hasn't fixed the problem of pin PB (pin 3 in my case), not providing the expected 1.9V. May try reflowing again

[image: LTC2950 in schematic]

[image: ITS13FR2ST & TL6215RF200RDT pushbutton schematics]

I should also point out that there are two versions of this chip; one that asserts active low and another that asserts active high. From my understanding, I purchased a chip that asserts active high, and my understanding from the datasheets is that both regulators take that too.

I can also confirm that the PB pin isn't shorted to ground until the button is pressed and held. That said, I did notice that the PB pin has basically no voltage on it according to the multimeter, as opposed to having internal bias voltage of 1.9V it's supposed to have, according to page 6 of the datasheet. Does anyone have any idea what the problem might be?

Comment: Two things: Your enable output is open-drain, so it needs a pull-up from somewhere. If one of the things it's turning on has a built-in pull-up, that's fine. Second, one of your "power_pulldown" labels seems to be misplaced, so if you made a board off of this schematic (or you're running a simulation off it) your button will never do anything.

Comment: @Hearth I moved that out of the way while I was capturing images. I can confirm the continuity is good, at least on a footprint level.

The pull-ups seem to be a different story. I'll double-check the datasheets. I may have further questions on that regarding the EN pin's maximum pull-up voltage of 10V